# regex, repeat, count group

Tags: regex, count, repeat, regex-group

i need some help with a regex that follows up this format:

First part of the string is a email address, followed by eight columns divided by `";"`.

```
a.test@test.com;Alex;Test;Alex A.Test;Alex;12;34;56;78
```

the first part i have is (`.*@.*com`)

these are also possible source strings:

```
a.test@test.com;Alex;;Alex A.Test;;12;34;56;78
a.test@test.com;Alex;;Alex A.Test;Alex;;34;;78
a.test@test.com;Alex;Test;;Alex;12;34;56; and so on
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: The easiest is to split your string by the semicolon in your programming language. What are you using (it's not regex)?

Comment: it is a bash script, so i will use sed for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
^(.*@.*com)(([^";\n]*|"[^"\n]*");){8}(([^";\n]*|"[^"\n]*"))$
```

If you have a different number of columns after the adress change the number between `{` and `}`

For your data here the catches:

```
1.  `a.test@test.com`
2.  `56;`
3.  `56`
4.  `78`
```

[Here the test](https://regex101.com/r/sF3jE5/1)

If you are sure there will be no `"` in your strings you can use this:

```
^(.*@.*com)(([^;\n]*);){8}([^;\n]*)$
```

[Here the test](https://regex101.com/r/sF3jE5/2)

**Edit:**

OP suggested this usage:
For use the first regex with `sed` you need `-i -n -E` flags and escape the `"` char.
The result will look like this:

```
sed -i -n -E "/(.*@.*com)(([^\";\n]*|\"[^\"\n]*\");){8}(([^\";\n]*|\"[^\"\n]*\"))/p"
```

Comment: this one does the job for me, thanks.  How must the sed command look like to print only lines following this pattern?

Comment: for the use of sed with regex look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/). Tell if is what you are looking for.

Comment: try this: `sed -i -E "/(.*@.*com)(([^\";\n]*|\"[^\"\n]*\");){8}(([^\";\n]*|\"[^\"\n]*\"))/p"`

Comment: sed -i -n -E "/(.*@.*com)(([^\";\n]*|\"[^\"\n]*\");){8}(([^\";\n]*|\"[^\"\n]*\"))/p" works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like

```
".*@.*\.com;[A-Z,a-z]*;[A-Z,a-z]*;[A-Z,a-z, ,.,]*;[A-Z,a-z]*;[0-9][0-9];[0-9][0-9];[0-9][0-9];[0-9][0-9]"
```

Assuming the numbers are only two digit

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do this easily:

```
awk -F ';' '$1 ~ /\.com$/{print NF}' file

9
9
9

cat file

a.test@test.com;Alex;;Alex A.Test;;12;34;56;78
a.test@test.com;Alex;;Alex A.Test;Alex;;34;;78
a.test@test.com;Alex;Test;;Alex;12;34;56; and so on
```